# Pass Arguments to AWS Lambda via Dockerfile

Tags: aws-lambda, dockerfile

I have a jenkins pipeline (jenkinsfile) that is passing command line arguments to a dockerfile. If the arguments are echoed I can see they enter the dockerfile just fine.

The issue that I'm having is giving my lambda_handler these command line arguments. Normally the CMD run is just the lambda_handler.

```
CMD [ "lambda_handler.handler"]
```

However, the issue is when I also try to pass the command line arguments, I end up getting **"entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument"** when trying to test the lambda.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

ARG LAMBDA_NAME

ARG COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS
ENV COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS = $COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS

# Copy function code
COPY $LAMBDA_NAME/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/"

CMD [ "lambda_handler.handler", "COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS" ]
```

How can I successfully pass command line arguments to the lambda_handler?

Comment: Hi, you got solution for this ? I am in same situation.